# Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. TS2345

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I am running this code and have just seen this error appear.

```
import { ethers } from 'ethers'
import { getMulticallContract } from 'utils/contractHelpers'
import { MultiCallResponse } from './types'

export interface Call {
  address: string // Address of the contract
  name: string // Function name on the contract (example: balanceOf)
  params?: any[] // Function params
}

interface MulticallOptions {
  requireSuccess?: boolean
}

const multicall = async <T = any>(abi: any[], calls: Call[]): Promise<T> => {
  try {
    const multi = getMulticallContract()
    const itf = new ethers.utils.Interface(abi)

    const calldata = calls.map((call) => [call.address.toLowerCase(), itf.encodeFunctionData(call.name, call.params)])
    const { returnData } = await multi.aggregate(calldata)

    const res = returnData.map((call, i) => itf.decodeFunctionResult(calls[i].name, call))
    

    return res
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error)
  }
}
```

This is the error that I'm getting, although until now this has been running just fine.

```
Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.  TS2345

    28 |     return res
    29 |   } catch (error) {
  > 30 |     throw new Error(error)
       |                     ^
    31 |   }
    32 | }
    33 |
```

I've looked through related questions, but can't see any exact solution in this case, but also I'm learning typescript currently.

Comment: What if you do just "throw error" instead of "throw new Error(error)"

Comment: What exactly is the point of the `catch` clause? What kind of `error` do you expect the code in the `try` block to throw?

Answer (score 2):

In the end I just added `"useUnknownInCatchVariables": false,` to tsconfig and it stopped errors from being converted to unknown, which is what was causing this issue.

I believe I have to upgrade typescript as well though, because there is a warning in tsconfig about this flag `Unknown compiler option 'useUnknownInCatchVariables'.`

Also see that another solution to this is mentioned in the docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#useUnknownInCatchVariables

```
try {
  // ...
} catch (err) {
  // We have to verify err is an
  // error before using it as one.
  if (err instanceof Error) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't turn off the check but rather fix your code. Arguably, if an `Error` instance was thrown, your call `new Error(error)` was broken.

Comment: Did you read this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#useUnknownInCatchVariables

The first line.. In TypeScript 4.0, support was added to allow changing the type of the variable in a catch clause from any to unknown.  The type of the variable changed, prior to that the error call worked just fine.

Comment: No, the code didn't work. Yes, the compiler didn't complain and now does, but passing an `Error` instance as the argument to `new Error` is wrong regardless what Typescript version you are using.

Comment: I don't know why this got downvoted. It's basically the same as recommended here: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/get-a-catch-block-error-message-with-typescript

Answer (score 0):

### **In a case like this, you would never know what type of error will be going to be thrown(`unknown`), and `new Error()` receives a string**

Based on the context of your `multicall` function, I would suggest that you put a meaningful string to that error (which production-grade web usually do)

**You would throw something like this:**

```
const multicall = async <T = any>(abi: any[], calls: Call[]): Promise<T> => {
  try {
    const multi = getMulticallContract();
    const itf = new ethers.utils.Interface(abi);

    const calldata = calls.map((call) => [
      call.address.toLowerCase(),
      itf.encodeFunctionData(call.name, call.params),
    ]);
    const { returnData } = await multi.aggregate(calldata);

    const res = returnData.map((call, i) => itf.decodeFunctionResult(calls[i].name, call));

    return res;
  } catch {
    throw new Error('something went wrong in the multical function');
  }
};
```